# Vagrant ssh closes connection after executing -t option

Tags: bash, ssh, vagrant

I'm trying to create a script that will bring up my vagrant VM (a Ubuntu box hosted on OSX) navigate to the correct directory and start up my virtual env. I've read that this command should work for me:

```
vagrant ssh -- -t 'some commands'
```

The commands execute correctly, I see their output, but then the connection closes as soon as the script or statement is done executing. Here is the exact statement I'm trying to run:

```
vagrant ssh -- -t 'source ~/env/bin/activate; cd /vagrant/refunite-web-touchpoint; pwd'
```

I get this output:

```
/vagrant/refunite-web-touchpoint
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Here is the script for now:

```
#!/bin/bash
vagrant up
vagrant ssh -- -t 'source ~/env/bin/activate; cd /vagrant/refunite-web-touchpoint; pwd'
```

Comment: vagrant currently doesn't support `-tty` so it simply refuses to accept the connection. That's why you see `stdin: is not a tty` error every time you run a vagrant provisioning process.